# How can I fix my code for calculating Body Mass Index for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.5.1, and I need to make a BMI calculator using the formula 703 * weight/height^2, after I input my height and weight, I get "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"

And I'm honestly not sure how to fix it. This is my code.

```
def calculateBMI():
    weight = input("Please enter weight in pounds: ")
    height = input("Please enter height in inches: ")

    return weight * ((703.0) / (height * height))

bmi = calculateBMI()

print ("""Your BMI is""", str(bmi))

if bmi < 18.5:
    print("You are underweight.")
elif bmi > 25:
    print("You are overweight.")
else:
    print ("You are of optimal weight.")
```

Comment: Does your real program have any indentation?

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3? Python2 has `raw_input`, Python3 doesn't.

Comment: yup, I just kind of sloppily indented here so I could post it.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4):

There are three errors in your program:

- Since you are using Python3, you need to use `input()`, not `raw_input()` to read the user's weight and height.
- You need to convert the user's data to a numeric type using `int()` or `float()`.
- Your indentation is incorrect.

Here is a program that works:

```
def calculateBMI():
    weight = int(input("Please enter weight: "))
    height = int(input("Please enter height: "))

    return weight * ((703.0) / (height * height))
bmi = calculateBMI()

print ("""Your BMI is""", str(bmi))

if bmi < 18.5:
    print("You are underweight.")
elif bmi > 25:
    print("You are overweight.")
else:
    print ("You are of optimal weight.")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does work. I also added weight "in pounds" and height "in inches" so that it's less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Before I help out, I just wanted to point out that the code you have pasted has no indentation.  Python is indentation-sensitive -- did you just paste it wrong, or is this how your code actually looks? :)

Now, there are probably two problems here:

1. **Python version**

When I try running this code, it is able to take input from the
    command line fine.  I am using Python 2.7.8.  The `raw_input` method
    has been renamed to `input` in Python 3.  So, if you are using
    Python 3, you should change the `raw_input` to `input`.

If you are on Linux, you can find out your Python version on the console like this:

```
    $ python --version
```

2. **Floats and strings**

When you take input from the command line, using `input` or `raw_input`, it is saved as a string, as shown here in the docs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

If you want to multiply the two values together, you have to convert them to float, like this:

```
weight = float(input("Please enter weight: "))
height = float(input("Please enter height: "))
```

I hope this solves your problems :)